# Simple uint128_t implementation

Tags: c++, integer, c++17

I made a simple `uint128_t` implementation for a project that I'm working on. The reason for not using for example `boost::uint128_t` is that it is not fully `constexpr` like I would like it to be.

For this reason, I only implemented the operators that I'm going to use. I'm for example not interested in `operator*`, as I will never multiply 2 such numbers. Same for `operator/` and others.

Any comments will be welcome! :)

```
#ifndef UINT128_HPP
#define UINT128_HPP

#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <ostream>



namespace types {

// special class to represent a 128 bit unsigned number
// some shortcuts were taken to not make it too unnecessary complex
struct uint128_t final {
    constexpr uint128_t() = default;

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t(T&& num) noexcept : array{ static_cast<std::uint64_t>(num), 0ull } {}

    template<typename T>
    friend constexpr uint128_t operator&(uint128_t lhs, T&& rhs) noexcept {
        return lhs &= rhs;
    }

    constexpr uint128_t& operator&=(const uint128_t& rhs) noexcept {
        array[0] &= rhs.array[0];
        array[1] &= rhs.array[1];
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator&=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        array[0] &= rhs;
        array[1] = 0;
        return *this;
    }



    template<typename T>
    friend constexpr uint128_t operator|(uint128_t lhs, T&& rhs) noexcept {
        return lhs |= rhs;
    }

    constexpr uint128_t& operator|=(const uint128_t& rhs) noexcept {
        array[0] |= rhs.array[0];
        array[1] |= rhs.array[1];
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator|=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        array[0] |= rhs;
        return *this;
    }



    template<typename T>
    friend constexpr uint128_t operator^(uint128_t lhs, T&& rhs) noexcept {
        return lhs ^= rhs;
    }

    constexpr uint128_t& operator^=(const uint128_t& rhs) noexcept {
        array[0] ^= rhs.array[0];
        array[1] ^= rhs.array[1];
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator^=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        array[0] ^= rhs;
        return *this;
    }



    friend constexpr uint128_t operator~(uint128_t value) noexcept {
        value.array = { ~value.array[0], ~value.array[1] };
        return value;
    }



    template<typename T>
    friend constexpr uint128_t operator<<(uint128_t lhs, T&& rhs) noexcept {
        return lhs <<= rhs;
    }

    constexpr uint128_t& operator<<=(const uint128_t& rhs) noexcept {
        if (rhs.array[1] > 0)
            return array = {}, *this;
        return *this <<= rhs.array[0];
    }

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator<<=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (rhs == 0)
            return *this;

        const auto backup = array[1];
        array[1] = array[0];
        if (rhs < 64) {
            array[0] <<= rhs;
            array[1] >>= 64 - rhs;
            array[1] |= backup << rhs;
        }
        else {
            array[0] = 0;
            array[1] <<= rhs - 64;
        }

        return *this;
    }



    template<typename T>
    friend constexpr uint128_t operator>>(uint128_t lhs, T&& rhs) noexcept {
        return lhs >>= rhs;
    }

    constexpr uint128_t& operator>>=(const uint128_t& rhs) noexcept {
        if (rhs.array[1] > 0)
            return array = {}, *this;
        return *this >>= rhs.array[0];
    }

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator>>=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (rhs == 0)
            return *this;

        const auto backup = array[0];
        array[0] = array[1];
        if (rhs < 64) {
            array[1] >>= rhs;
            array[0] <<= 64 - rhs;
            array[0] |= backup >> rhs;
        }
        else {
            array[1] = 0;
            array[0] >>= rhs - 64;
        }

        return *this;
    }



    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr bool operator==(T&& rhs) const noexcept {
        return array[0] == static_cast<std::uint64_t>(rhs) && array[1] == 0;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const uint128_t& rhs) const noexcept {
        return array[0] == rhs.array[0] && array[1] == rhs.array[1];
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool operator!=(T&& rhs) const noexcept {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr bool operator<(T&& rhs) const noexcept {
        return array[0] < static_cast<std::uint64_t>(rhs) && array[1] == 0;
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(const uint128_t& rhs) const noexcept {
        if (array[1] == rhs.array[1])
            return array[0] < rhs.array[0];
        return array[1] < rhs.array[1];
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>(T&& rhs) const noexcept {
        return *this >= rhs && *this != rhs;
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<=(T&& rhs) const noexcept {
        return !(*this > rhs);
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>=(T&& rhs) const noexcept {
        return !(*this < rhs);
    }



    template<typename T>
    friend constexpr uint128_t operator+(uint128_t lhs, T&& rhs) noexcept {
        return lhs += rhs;
    }

    constexpr uint128_t& operator+=(const uint128_t& rhs) noexcept {
        *this += rhs.array[0];
        array[1] += rhs.array[1];
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator+=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        // overflow guard
        if (array[0] + rhs < array[0])
            ++array[1];
        array[0] += rhs;
        return *this;
    }



    template<typename T>
    friend constexpr uint128_t operator-(uint128_t lhs, T&& rhs) noexcept {
        return lhs -= rhs;
    }

    constexpr uint128_t& operator-=(const uint128_t& rhs) noexcept {
        *this -= rhs.array[0];
        array[1] -= rhs.array[1];
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator-=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        // overflow guard
        if (array[0] - rhs > array[0])
            --array[1];
        array[0] -= rhs;
        return *this;
    }



    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const uint128_t& num) noexcept {
        return stream << '[' << num.array[0] << " + " << "2**64 * " << num.array[1] << ']';
    }
private:
    std::array<uint64_t, 2> array{};
};

}

#endif
```

Comment: Note: I marked this review as C++17, although I think it should be able to compile under C++14. The reason being is that I would like to leverage newer features if possible :)

Comment: Why not take `boost::uint128_t` upgrade it. Then you can submit it back to boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Avoid Simple Header Guard Collisions**

```
#ifndef UINT128_HPP
#define UINT128_HPP
```

Don't just name the guard after the filename.  Append differentiators (file path, [GUID](https://guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx), date, etc) to minimize the chance of collision.  An example

```
<project>_<path_part1>_..._<path_partN>_<file>_<extension>_<guid>

// include/pet/project/file.hpp
#ifndef PET_PROJECT_FILE_HPP_68B24FD6E49248409028D9814FE4CD515
```

---

**Negative Values**

```
    template<typename T, typename = 
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t(T&& num) noexcept 
      : array{ static_cast<std::uint64_t>(num), 0ull } {}
```

The integral conversion rules for values with an unsigned destination is defined.  From the C++ standard (n4659 §7.8.2):

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo \$2^n\$ where *n* is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [*Note*: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). — *end note*]

Say we want to the maximum value of `uint128_t`.  For the built-in integral types, we can construct them with the value `-1`.  Constructing a `uint128_t` with a value of `-1` only sets the low bits.  You should check to see if `num` is negative and set the high bits appropriately.

```
    template<typename T, typename = 
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t(T&& num) noexcept 
      : array{ static_cast<std::uint64_t>(num)
             , static_cast<std::uint64_t>((num >= 0) ? 0 : -1) } {}
```

Your functions that take a templated integral argument need to be corrected.

---

**Undefined Behavior**

```
    template<typename T, typename = 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator<<=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (rhs == 0)
            return *this;

        const auto backup = array[1];
        array[1] = array[0];
        if (rhs < 64) {
            array[0] <<= rhs;
            array[1] >>= 64 - rhs;
            array[1] |= backup << rhs;
        }
        else {
            array[0] = 0;
            array[1] <<= rhs - 64;
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

In your final `else` block, you have undefined behavior if `rhs >= 128` (n4659 §8.8.1).

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. The behavior is undeﬁned if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

```
    template<typename T, typename = 
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr uint128_t& operator<<=(T&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (rhs < 64) {
            if (rhs != 0) {
                array[1] = (array[1] << rhs) | (array[0] >> (64 - rhs));
                array[0] = array[0] << rhs;
            }
        }                
        else if (rhs < 128) {
            array[0] = 0;
            array[1] = array[1] << (rhs - 64);
        }
        else {
            array = {};
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

---

**Don't Abuse the Comma Operator**

```
    constexpr uint128_t& operator>>=(const uint128_t& rhs) noexcept {
        if (rhs.array[1] > 0)
            return array = {}, *this;
        return *this >>= rhs.array[0];
    }
```

---

**Simplifying The Comparators**

```
    constexpr bool operator==(const uint128_t& rhs) const noexcept {
        return array[0] == rhs.array[0] && array[1] == rhs.array[1];
    }
```

`std::tuple` (requires `<tuple>`) provides simple lexicographical comparisons that works at compile-time (unlike `std::array`s comparators).  We can create `std::tuple`s on the fly with `std::tie()`.

```
    constexpr auto tie() const noexcept {
        return std::tie(array[1], array[0]);
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const uint128_t& rhs) const noexcept {
        return tie() == rhs.tie();
    }

    constexpr bool operator<(const uint128_t& rhs) const noexcept {
        return tie() < rhs.tie();
    }

    // ...
```

You'll notice that many of your functions have the same boilerplate.  You can use the pre-processor to generate all of the comparators.

```
    #define COMP128(op)                                               \
    constexpr bool operator op(const uint128_t& rhs) const noexcept { \
        return tie() op rhs.tie();                                    \
    }

    COMP128(==)
    COMP128(!=)
    COMP128(>=)
    COMP128(<=)
    COMP128(>)
    COMP128(<)

    #undef COMP128
```

Similarly, the preprocessor could also be used to generate the logic/logic-assignment operators.

---

```
    std::array<uint64_t, 2> array{};
```

The use of `std::array<>` feels like unnecessary obfuscation.  I'd recommend using two variables with descriptive names (like `lo` and `hi`).

Comment: Thanks! `lo` and `hi` aren't very descriptive though :)

Comment: @Rakete1111, I'm afraid you're not old enough to understand them :) I'm pretty young too though.

Comment: Just as a heads-up, your point about undefined behavior relies on the existence of 128bit numbers on a specific platform. Ignoring the fact that there is probably no platform having that behavior, a lot of my other code would also be wrong as a result of 128bit intergers.